# Reading stream in chunks fails - destination array not long enough

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently writing some code to process and encrypt an uploaded file in ASP. My first attempt works (even for large files) but takes a while to process on the server end. I believed this was because I was doing this byte by byte.  Here is working code...

```
using (RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged())
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = rm.CreateEncryptor(drfObject.DocumentKey, drfObject.DocumentIV))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                int data;
                while ((data = inputStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
                    cs.WriteByte((byte)data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As said previously, the above code works fine but is slow when processing at the server end. So I thought I'd try to read in the bytes in blocks to speed things up (no idea if this would / should make a difference or not).  I tried this code...

```
int bytesToRead = (int)inputStream.Length;
int numBytesRead = 0;
int byteBuffer = 8192;

using (RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged())
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = rm.CreateEncryptor(drfObject.DocumentKey, drfObject.DocumentIV))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fs, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                do
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[byteBuffer];

                    // This line throws 'Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.'
                    int n = inputStream.Read(data, numBytesRead, byteBuffer);

                    cs.Write(data, numBytesRead, n);

                    numBytesRead += n;
                    bytesToRead -= n;

                } while (bytesToRead > 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, as indicated in the code - when I upload a large file now, I get "**Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds**" error.  I read various posts about padding but even increasing the data byte array to double the size still gives the error.

I've no doubt I'm missing something obvious.  Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int n = inputStream.Read(data, numBytesRead, byteBuffer);
```

should be

```
int n = inputStream.Read(data, 0, byteBuffer);
```

because the number you put there is the offset *of the buffer you are reading to*, not the offset of the stream.

Comment: Well spotted. In addition however, the 'cs.write' line should also have an offset of zero - but it all worked after those changes. Many thanks,